# playing midi sounds through pygame on raspberrypi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, midi

I'm trying to play midi sounds using pygame on my raspberrypi (without external midi devices), however I can't get anything to work.

I have tried many examples:
The following gives.

```
import pygame
import time
import pygame.midi

pygame.midi.init()
player= pygame.midi.Output(0)
player.set_instrument(48,1)

major=[0,4,7,12]

def go(note):
    player.note_on(note, 127,1)
    time.sleep(1)
    player.note_off(note,127,1)

def arp(base,ints):
    for n in ints:
        go(base+n)

def chord(base, ints):
    player.note_on(base,127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[1],127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[2],127,1)
    player.note_on(base+ints[3],127,1)
    time.sleep(1)
    player.note_off(base,127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[1],127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[2],127,1)
    player.note_off(base+ints[3],127,1)
def end():
       pygame.quit()
```

Gives the following error

```
PortMidi call failed...
  PortMidi: 'Bad pointer'
type ENTER...
```

The next example (like most of the others) gives a 'Device id invalid, out of range.' error:

```
import pygame
import pygame.midi
from time import sleep

instrument = 0
note = 74
volume = 127

pygame.init()
pygame.midi.init()

for id in range(pygame.midi.get_count()):
  print pygame.midi.get_device_info(id)

port = 2
midiOutput = pygame.midi.Output(port, 1)
midiOutput.set_instrument(instrument)
for note in range(0,127):
  midiOutput.note_on(note,volume)
  sleep(.25)
  midiOutput.note_off(note,volume)
del midiOutput
pygame.midi.quit()
```

Gives this error

```
('ALSA', 'Midi Through Port-0', 0, 1, 0)
('ALSA', 'Midi Through Port-0', 1, 0, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "midi-test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    midiOutput = pygame.midi.Output(port, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygame/midi.py", line 414, in __init__
    raise MidiException("Device id invalid, out of range.")
pygame.midi.MidiException: 'Device id invalid, out of range.'
```

I haven't found any guides to setting up a RaspberryPi to play midi sounds, any suggestions?

Comment: As it is actually no answer to your question, but another way of doing what you seem to want, check that link: [link](http://hackaday.com/2013/01/22/raspberry-pi-plays-midi-without-an-operating-system/) This might be adaptable...

Comment: What software synthesizer are you using?

Answer (score -1):

port = 2
midiOutput = pygame.midi.Output(port, 1)

I do not know the "pygame.midi" I do not know if you can do this, but changing the parameters, the code ran without errors.

midiOutput = pygame.midi.Output(0, 0)